# Why can't I upload a video (mp4 file)?

Tags: php, cakephp, video, file-upload, cakephp-3.0

I am currently trying to upload files to the web application. It this code below allows me to upload any file besides video (e.g. mp4) files. This is using CakePHP 3.0.11

```
if (isset($_FILES['uploads']) === true) {
   //put the data into a var
   $file = $_FILES['uploads'];
   for ($i = 0; $i < count($file['name']); $i++) {
        $name = $file['name'][$i];
        $tmp_name = $file['tmp_name'] [$i];

        // upload file and move to img/uploads/itemsImages
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, WWW_ROOT . 'img/modulevideos/' . $name);

       // prepare the filename for database entry
       $moduleContent['content'] = 'modulevideos/' . $name ;



       echo $name, '<br>';
       echo $tmp_name, '<br>';
       echo $moduleContent['content'], '<br>';
   }
 }
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in your apache log?

Comment: 1. You don't need `===true`, `isset()`, just `isset()`. 2. there surely needs to be some sort of error being invoked when uploading the video files.

Comment: you are not checking if there was an error with the file upload. See the php manual: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script to upload any file.

```
<?php
$target_dir = "/img/uploads/itemsImages";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if (isset($_FILES['uploads'])) {
$check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an valid file - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
} else { 
    $uploadOk = 1;
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
}
}
?>
```

If you want to only allow files then include this before the uploadOK check.

```
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "mp4") {
echo "Sorry file type now allowed";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
```